# Kendo react scheduler dialog

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I am trying to add an input control in kendo react scheduler dialog model .How to add extra input control in kendo react scheduler dialog ? Can anyone help me out this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Show your code snippet.